# python class method mocking failure

Tags: python, flask, mocking, patch

Trying to understand mocking/patching and I have a restful API project with three files (FYI, I'm using flask)

1. class1.py
2. domain.py
3. test_domain.py

class1.py file content:

```
class one:
    def addition(self):
       return 4+5
```

domain.py file content:

```
from class1 import one

class DomainClass(Resource):

    def post(self):

        test1 = one()
        val = test1.addition()

        return {'test' : val }
```

test_domain.py file content:

```
import my_app
from flask_api import status
from mock import patch

app = my_app.app.test_client()

def test_post():
    with patch('domain.one') as mock:
        instance = mock.return_value
        instance.addition.return_value = 'yello'

    url = '/domain'
    response = app.post(url)
    print response.data

    assert status.HTTP_200_OK == response.status_code
    assert mock.called
```

For my test_domain.py file, I've also tried this...

```
@patch('domain.one')
def test_post(mock_domain):
    mock_domain.addition.return_value = 1

    url = '/domain'
    response = app.post(url)
    print response.data

    assert status.HTTP_200_OK == response.status_code
```

My assert for the status of 200 passes, however, the problem is that I'm not able to mock or patch the addition method to give me value of 1 in place of 9 (4+5). I also tried doing 'assert mock.called' and it failes as well. I know I should be mocking/patching where the 'one()' method is used, i.e. in domain.py not in class1.py. But I tried even mocking class1.one in place of domain.one and I still kept getting 9 and not 1. What am I doing wrong ?

******** Update
I've another dilemma on the same issue, I tried doing this in the test_domain file instead of patching....

```
from common.class1 import one
def test_post():
    one.addition = MagicMock(return_value=40)

    url = '/domain'
    response = app.post(url)
    print response.data

    assert status.HTTP_200_OK == response.status_code
```

Question

1. In update above, I did not do a mock at the place where it is used (i.e.: domain.one.addition = MagicMock(...) and it still worked !!!! It seems it may be doing a global change. Why did this work ?
2. In the above example, 'one' is a class in the module class1.py. If I change this class 'one' to a function in class1.py, mocking does not work. It seems this function 'one' residing in module class1.py can not be mocked like this...one.return_value = 'xyz', why? Can it be mocked globally ?

Comment: In your first example of `test_post()` the code from `url = '/domain'` to `assert mock.called` should be correctly indented in the `with` context. It is just a typo error or it is a real issue in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in your code. In the first example you forgot that `patch()` is applied in `with` context and the original code is recovered when the context end. Follow code should work:

```
def test_post():
    with patch('domain.one') as mock:
        instance = mock.return_value
        instance.addition.return_value = 'yello'
        url = '/domain'
        response = app.post(url)
        print response.data
        assert status.HTTP_200_OK == response.status_code
        assert mock.called
        assert response.data['test'] == 'yello'
```

The second one have an other issue: if you want patch just `addition` method you should use:

```
@patch('domain.one.addition')
def test_post(mock_addition):
    mock_addition.return_value = 1
    ...
    assert mock_addition.called
    assert response.data['test'] == 1
```

If you want mock *all `one` class* you should set the return value of `addition` method of *mock instance returned by `mock_domain` call* like in your first example:

```
@patch('domain.one')
def test_post(mock_domain):
    mock_addition = mock_domain.return_value.addition
    mock_addition.return_value = 1
    ...
    assert mock_addition.called
    assert response.data['test'] == 1
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I had figured how the decorator solution worked but not the one with 'with'.

Comment: @ParindShah The one with `with` is the simplest one... You had already write the right code but **all your test should be in `with` context** otherwise when you exit from `with` the original not mocked code is recovered and your test will use the no mocked `one` class.

Comment: Thank u much. I knew this cork with 'with' very much but seemed to forgot, thanks for reminding. However, I have posted a new update on the question. I would appreciate any thought on these two new questions. Also, any thoughts on when to use a patch and when to use a mock ?

Comment: @ParindShah Please remove your edit part from the question (don't edit a question if you have an accepted answer yet... make the question just more confused). If you have an other question post a new one and use the link to the original one if it is relevant to understand the newer. Anyway I can answer to the new topics: take care that you are working with **reference** and not **copy**: by `from a import b` you create a a new **reference** to `b` in new module and by change `b.something` you are changing the **refence** of  `b.something` in the origina class definition.